# Isomorphism between quotient spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, quotient-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $V$ and $W$ be isomorphic vector spaces (not necessarily finite dimensional) over the same field ($\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$) via a linear isomorphism $f:V\to W$. Suppose $V_1, V_2$ are linear subspaces of $V$, and $W_1, W_2$ are linear subspaces of $W$ so that
$$V=V_1\oplus V_2,\qquad W=W_1\oplus W_2.$$
Suppose $V_1$ and $W_1$ are isomorphic via a linear isomorphism $g:V_1\to W_1$. We know that $V_2$ and $W_2$ are not isomorphic in general, even though $V_2\cong V/V_1$ and $W_2\cong W/W_1$.

My question is, is there any criterion so that $V_2\cong W_2$? That is, any criterion which makes $V\cong W$ and $V_1\cong W_1$ imply $V/V_1\cong W/W_1$?

Edit: I should mention that, in the case I am considering, $V$, $V_1$, $W$ and $W_1$ are infinite dimensional, and $V_2$ and $W_2$ are finite dimensional.

Comment: well, in finite dimension it is true

Comment: @Exodd Yes. But what about if $V$ and $W$ are infinite dimensional? Actually, in the case I am considering, $V_1$ and $W_1$ are infinite dimensional as well, but $V_2$ and $W_2$ are finite dimensional.

Comment: if the isomorphism of $V,W$ induces the one of $V_1,W_1$, then it should be true too

Comment: I think if we accept AC, this question is approximately the same as "if $|A| = |B|$, $A' \subseteq A$, $B' \subseteq B$, $|A'| = |B'|$, then when $|A \setminus A'| = |B \setminus B'|$". Doesn't seem likely to have better characterisation than the trivial.

Comment: @mihaild Thanks. And yes, I don't think there is a good sufficient condition for my question, sigh...